# How to select areas in the same layer the shader Editor paints?

Tags: modeling, texturing, shaders, edit-mode, windows

[image]

Hello, so I created a house in 3D and want to texture it with the shader editor. Problem is that the whole house is on the "cube" layer, because I build it manually instead of building tool addon. Is there retrospectively a way to select specific areas in the same layer to paint it with the shader editor?
The only solution I can think of is to somehow split my "cube" layer into sections on different layers and apply the shader afterward. But how that would work would be my second question..

Best

Answer (score 1):

When you create a material it gets assigned automatically to the whole object (in your scene the "Cube" object, which is not a layer but a 3D object).

To manage your texturing you have to create as many materials as the number of different textures you need to use, and assign in edit mode all different materials to the selected faces.

If at the end of the process you need to export your object with a single material, you will have to "Bake" all your different textures into a single group of textures (Color texture, Normal map texture, roughness texture, and so on ...), apply them on a single material, and assign this new material to the whole object.

[image]

Comment: IIRC, it's the material in slot 0 that gets added to the whole object, so technically, it's the first material you create.  Is my memory correct?